# OpenVPN start at boot not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, boot, start

I am trying do configure my **Ubuntu 14.04** server, so **OpenVPN** will **start at boot**.
So far, I am able to start OpenVPN server with the command:

```
service openvpn start
```

After I execute this command, I am prompted for the private key password, and after entering the password OpenVPN starts and runs with no issues.
To make it start at boot, I have uncommented the AUTOSTART="all" line in /etc/init/d/openvpn, and I have added the symlinks to the runlevel folders with the command:

```
update-rc.d openvpn enable 2345
```

After executing this last command, the links are created for all run levels, but I also get the following errors:

```
update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match openvpn Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)  
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match openvpn Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
```

After rebooting my server, OpenVPN doesn't start.
What is it that I am missing/doing wrong here?
My own understanding is that, somewhere along the line, I should enable the OpenVPN daemon to start without needing the server's private key password. No one is mentioning anything about the private key password anywhere in the other posts regarding OpenVPN autostart issues that are out there, so I don't know... Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As long as you haven't removed the password from your private key, you need to enter it when starting OpenVPN, no matter if it is automatic or manual start.

Comment: Makes sense.. I did that, and it works now. Thank you for the help :)!